# Can I have 2 different networking interfaces active at the same time to increase my available bandwidth?

Tags: macbook-pro, network

Android devices have a "Dual Networks" feature where you can use both the wifi and 3G network adapters concurrently to increase your available bandwidth:

[image: Screenshot of Android settings interface with Dual networks highlighted]

Can I do something similar with my MacBook Pro, for example if I have both ethernet and wifi connections?

Assume that the wired connection uses a different router/gateway than the wireless one.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your NIC priority is in effect to determine which interface to use preferentially. So either your built-in ethernet or your wireless card leads depending on your gateway settings to a target. Both may be in effect but not at the same time to one and the same target.

However a second ethernet card added to an expansion slot (e.g. ExpressCard/34) may be bonded to your internal ethernet card. This is known as [Link Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) or `Port Bonding` and `Port Teaming`. Both have to master LACP (Link Aggregation Control Protocol) or IEEE 802.1ax and IEEE 802.3ad though. And the switch at the other end needs to support it also and usually has to be configured for it on your two ports.

The latest Mac Pro as well as the older ones with 2 NICs are capable of doing such right out of the box.

Comment: How would this work on a MacBook Pro (as stated in the question)?

Comment: @patrix as stated in my answer: a second ethernet card added to an expansion slot may work

Comment: AFAIK the MacBook Pro doesn't have an expansion slot

Comment: @patrix depends on the MacBook Pro. My [MacBookPro8,3](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-17-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) has an expansion slot.